# Display Interface vs APL

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

Please clarify on What is the difference between Display Interface vs APL in Alexa Skill?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few differences mostly in terms of the interactions, usage of data to show on the screen and so on. With the Display Interface you have a set list of templates shown [here](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/display-template-reference.html), where APL shines is when offering more flexibility to show graphics that is bind to data and add interactive screens, also allows you to create slide shows, and provides more tools to customize the whole visual experience. For example you can highlight part of the text like a Karaoke song lyrics for example. In APL the interactions trigger events and state changes, for example, lets say that you a button and that makes Alexa use SSML or TTS to say something, that you can't do with a Display Interface.

Probably [this](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/alexa-presentation-language/apl-overview.html) can clarify a bit more.

I hope this helps.
Cheers